# Auto-incrementing variable on iMacros without loop

Tags: auto-increment, imacros

Here's my current iMacro code I need help with:

```
`VERSION BUILD=8961227 RECORDER=FX
SET !LOOP 1
SET !var1 
add !var1 {{!loop}}
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:tsf ATTR=ID:lst-ib CONTENT={{!var1}}`
```

This code works fine with loop mode,but i want to auto-increment the var1 in each manual execution

Test1 :
    `TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:tsf ATTR=ID:lst-ib CONTENT=1`

Test 2:     `TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:tsf ATTR=ID:lst-ib CONTENT=2`

I hope to be clear, thanks for helping me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
VERSION BUILD=8961227 RECORDER=FX
SET !DATASOURCE NUM.csv
SET !VAR1 {{!COL1}}
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:tsf ATTR=ID:lst-ib CONTENT={{!VAR1}}
**FILEDELETE NAME=C:\Users\Th3\Documents\iMacros\Datasources\NUM.CSV** 
ADD !VAR1 1
SET !EXTRACT {{!VAR1}}
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\Users\Th3\Documents\iMacros\Datasources FILE=NUM.CSV
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try [EVAL](http://wiki.imacros.net/EVAL):

```
SET !VAR1 1
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:tsf ATTR=ID:lst-ib CONTENT={{!VAR1}}
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var s=\"{{!VAR1}}\"; parseInt(s)+1;")
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:tsf ATTR=ID:lst-ib CONTENT={{!VAR1}}
```

Comment: Thanks!
but the result is '2' every time this is not what I want.

I want to increase the variable by 1 every execution of imacros script
first execution : 1
second execution : 2
third execution : 3
...

Comment: I thought a bit
`VERSION BUILD=8961227 RECORDER=FX
SET !DATASOURCE NUM.csv
SET !VAR1 {{!COL1}}
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:tsf ATTR=ID:lst-ib CONTENT={{!VAR1}}
ADD !VAR1 1
SET !EXTRACT {{!VAR1}}
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\Users\Th3\Documents\iMacros\Datasources FILE=NUM.CSV`
but how can i edit !COL1 and not adding the value in an other COL thanks